# Will my potential military service obligations impact travel to other countries?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports

I am planning on going for a holiday, and I only have a UK passport which shows my nationality as British citizen. In Turkey and North Cyprus (where my parents are from), I would, as a consequence of my parentage, be conscripted.

I have no plans to visit Turkey or Northern Cyprus, but I really want to travel around the world and explore new countries as I am soon turning 19! Will I have any issues when I am traveling? For example, at immigration in other countries, will my passport be flagged for avoiding the Turkish  military service?

Comment: I would suggest researching the laws of the *Republic of Cyprus*.  They also have conscription; it is possible, given their claim to the whole island, that they might want to draft you as well.  (I'm not certain if they draft ethnic Turks, but definitely worth researching)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will not have any trouble with border crossings of this nature as a UK citizen. For example, border control in Brazil will have no idea where your parents are from and won't care. They will see your UK passport, and let you in for 90 days visa free, just like any other UK citizen.

If you have no plans to visit Turkey or North Cyprus, then you will have nothing to worry about. If you do, then the details of what happens depends on whether they consider you a citizen of their country, and what their rules are for mandatory service.

Your UK passport offers you a [great many places to visit with no visa required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_British_citizens). For the rest of the world, visitor visas are usually pretty easy to get.

[image]

Comment: so there will be no flags when they check my passport like arrest warrant or anything saying i'm a draft dodger lol i will just be viewed and seen as British in other countries? thanks for the help :)

Comment: @gully0923: Military service would be a matter only between you and the country of which you're a citizen. No other country cares, and global police work such as through Interpol is only reserved for exceptionally serious cases. But really, if you were born in the UK and never registered or whatever you might be required to do as to be known as a Turkish citizen, then how would they even know? Your passport doesn't contain your parents' names. Turkey doesn't have a record of your birth. There's no way for them to connect the dots. Having a Turkish name is hardly enough.

Comment: oh alright great hahah thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @gully0923: To specifically answer your question, presenting a British passport on entry to any other country in the world, you will be seen and treated only as a British citizen. There are millions of people from all kinds of different ethnic backgrounds who also hold British passports, so it's definitely not anything unusual. Not a single border guard anywhere in the rest of the world will even think to wonder whether you've done your Turkish military service simply because you have a Turkish sounding name.

Comment: thanks for all the help :) its great to know i wont be having any arrest warrants out for me lol and all my crazy ideas and scenarios i have thought up hahaha will not be any issue. I defo overthink things i already know would not be a problem  like im on a British passport the only country who could do anything would be the UK lmao but yeah thanks for all the help once again  i will be booking a holiday to Spain next month hahaha